# Can I know from the callback function, if user shared the link with "Friends" or "Only me"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile, unity-game-engine

I'm making a mobile game in which the player can Share his score. 
I want to know whether he shared with "Only me" or with all his friends.

Can this information be retrieved from the callback function?

The Facebook documentation says the Response Data is "post_id", but I'm not sure I searched the right docs.

Comment: Simple answer - you cannot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case that you are using the FB API for unity3d you must have taken a look at Free Dialog API, which is here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2?locale=es_ES

As the API says, the `post_id` parameter allow you to get *"The ID of the posted story, if the person chose to publish."*. This means that you don't have access to more information than this ID number.

So, for getting your posting recipient ("Only me" or "Your friends") you have to get the information from your FB API request. If you get the request information you can acces to the `to` parameter and get the recipients from it.